# How to vectorize my function in R?

Tags: r, function

I write a function in R as following, but I could not use it in a vectorize way (the second part of the code below). I am wondering how can I make this function vectorize

```
normalize=function(browser){
   if (browser=="Chrome" | browser=="Firefox" | browser=='Safari' | grepl('IE',browser)){
     browser
   }else{
     "Others"
   }
}

data$browser_n<-normalize(data$browser)      // not working (data is a data frame)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this may not be most correct answer, you can try `Vectorize`. In general, you can use `Vectorize` on many functions to vectorize them. I should add that `Vectorize` is just a pretty wrapper around `mapply`

```
normalize = function(browser) {
    if (browser == "Chrome" | browser == "Firefox" | browser == "Safari" | grepl("IE", browser)) {
        return(browser)
    } else {
        return("Others")
    }
}

vNormalize <- Vectorize(normalize)

data <- data.frame(browser = c("Chrome", "Firefox", "Safari", "IE 10"))

vNormalize(data$browser)
## [1] Chrome  Firefox Safari  IE 10  
## Levels: Chrome Firefox IE 10 Safari
```

Comment: this is vectorized in appearance (hiding loops), but much less efficient than @EDi 's answer which uses truly vectorized operations, I believe using `Vectorize` on your own functions is not generally good practice

Answer (score 3):

Use ifelse():

```
normalize=function(browser){
  ifelse(browser=="Chrome" | browser=="Firefox" | browser=='Safari' | grepl('IE',browser), browser, 'Others')
}

browser <- c('aaa', 'Chrome')
normalize(browser) 
# [1] "Others" "Chrome"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
normalize <- function(browser){
  replace(browser, !(browser %in% c("Chrome", "Firefox", "Safari") | 
                     grepl('IE',browser)), "Others")  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are two comments.

It would be better to use `||` instead of `|`. Here is why.

> & and && indicate logical AND and | and || indicate logical OR. The shorter form performs elementwise comparisons in much the same way as arithmetic operators. The longer form evaluates left to right examining only the first element of each vector. Evaluation proceeds only until the result is determined. The longer form is appropriate for programming control-flow and typically preferred in if clauses.

Another approach would be to use `any`.

```
 normalize = function(browser){
   if (any(browser == "Chrome", browser == "Firefox", browser == "Safari",
     grepl("IE", browser)) {
     browser
   } else {
     "Others
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you are not really interested in vectorization, but want to get the new variable `browser_n` as in your example, you could just write

```
data$browser_n<-data$browser
data$browser_n[!(data$browser=="Chrome" | data$browser=="Firefox" | 
               data$browser=='Safari' | grepl('IE',data$browser))] <- "Others"
```